# Nitrous.io, Python and Cron not working

Tags: python, linux, cron, nitrousio

Since my script works well when calling it from command line. I'm trying to run this code on schedule with cron:

```
with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Hello world! \n')
```

And I've set `chmod a+x hello_world.py`

But I want to run it in Nitrous.io with python3.3, since `which python` and `which python3.3` returns `/home/action/.parts/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python3.3` respectively. I have tried to add some shebangs at the start of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/python3.3
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3
#!/home/action/.parts/bin/python (Weird, I know...)
```

The command `python` returns a 2.7.6 python shell and `python3.3` or `/usr/bin/python3.3` returns a 3.3.5 python shell. And `ls /usr/bin/python*` outputs:

```
/usr/bin/python            /usr/bin/python2.6-config  /usr/bin/python3.2-config    /usr/bin/python3.3m                             
/usr/bin/python2           /usr/bin/python2.7         /usr/bin/python3.2mu         /usr/bin/python3.3m-config                      
/usr/bin/python2.5         /usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3.2mu-config  /usr/bin/python-config                          
/usr/bin/python2.5-config  /usr/bin/python2-config    /usr/bin/python3.3                                                           
/usr/bin/python2.6         /usr/bin/python3.2         /usr/bin/python3.3-config
```

I also added python paths to PATH and PYTHONPATH:

```
#PATH=/usr/bin/python3.3:/home/action/.parts/bin:/home/action/.parts/sbin:/home/action/.parts/autoparts/bin:/home/action/.parts/autoparts/bin:/home/action/.parts/autoparts/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/action/.gem/ru
by/1.9.1/bin   

#PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3.3
```

`pidof cron` is returning the Process ID of cron.

I tried to redirect the output with `... > /path/to/cron.log 2&>1` without success. And derivatives...

My crontab -e file looks like:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3.3
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.3 /home/action/workspace/hello_world.py
```

But I can't get it to work...
Can anyone help this litle guy ? :)

Comment: Have you checked the log file where your cron job gets logged to? Because, there might be a permission related errors regarding opening or writing to that file. To find where it gets logged to, you might want to take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged or http://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log.

Comment: In Nitrous.io there's no root. I can't check grep CRON /var/log/syslog :(
I have managed to make `* * * * * ls -la; >> /home/action/workspace/cron.log` so cron is working fine. I've also found a file in an odd path with the results of the script, so it worked at some time... I'm checking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess - your script is working fine. No output, no problem. Just not sure where the output file is.

For your code, try an absolute path.

```
with open('/tmp/out.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Hello world! \n')
```

---

As an aside - the #! doens't matter.

When you prefix the python script with the python interpreter:

```
/usr/bin/python3.3 <any-file>
```

the python interperter, not the shell, executes the file and will ignore the #! line.

Comment: I had realized by myself, but since you took the time to effectively write a correct answer and added some extra info... I'll give you kudos and accept it ! Oh man read my own answer, we were saying almost the same xD Thank you !

Comment: Heh, Thanks, appreciate it. I think we posted the answers at the same time. Glad you figured it out though.

Answer (score 0):

It was working ! Seems that in Nitrous the `~/actions/` act as a root directory. So If you try to do that:

```
with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Hello world! \n')
```

You're effectively creating a file with contents but in `~/actions/` and not in the current directory of the script file that is in `/home/actions/workbench/out.txt` to make it work as I was expecting I had to rewrite it as:

```
with open('workbench/out.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Hello world! \n')
```

No need for shebang nor PYTHONPATH in the crontab -e file. The cron command It's the same as above (in the question).